My Equations Won't Centre?
My equation won't centre I have tried so many different things. I can only centre with $$ abc $$ but I need all my equations to also be numbered.
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{olplainarticle}
% Use option lineno for line numbers 
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{parskip}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
 \setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip}
\title{Modern Methods of Computing Scattering Amplitudes}

\author[1]{}
\affil[1]{Address of first author}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

\begin{abstract}
This report begins by introducing the concept of scattering amplitudes and the motivation followed by review of spinor helicity and the kinematics of special relativity, which will be essential for our later discussion of discoveries for more modern techniques to compute scattering amplitudes in a more precise way than the traditional methods. We will then be fixing three-point amplitudes using little group scaling followed by a discussion of BCFW recursion relations with an overview of residue theorem. Finally, we end the main discourse with the derivation of Parke-Taylor formula for MHV amplitudes from BCFW recursion relations. After this, we finalise the report with closing remarks in a conclusion.
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{   Introduction}
\subsection{  Scattering Amplitudes}

What are scattering amplitudes and why study them? In QFT, or quantum field theory, scattering amplitudes are complex functions that measure the likelihood of particles scattering in a certain direction. The variation of the scattering angle is given by the differential cross-section given by the modulus of this probability amplitude (the complex function) squared as shown below in Eq(1).
\begin{equation}
     d\sigma=|f(\theta)|^2 d \Omega \
\end{equation}




You can think of scattering processes as an "exchange" such as two people standing on a boat each and passing a ball to each other with the ball representing what is known as a "force carrier" in this analogy. Whenever a ball is thrown, the thrower will experience a reaction force and consequently his boat moves back. Likewise, when the other person catches the ball, he experiences a backwards force and is carried backwards from the momentum of the ball as illustrated rather questionably in figure 1. It analogously demonstrates the phenomenon of repulsion.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{figures/97b445e5-5777-4f02-950f-c6d1e25d16a3.png}
    \caption{Image portraying two "boats" and people throwing a yellow ball back and forth. Image generated by ChatGPT, reference [1]}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

This analogy simplifies particle interactions where this "ball", or force carrier, represents particles such as photons, gluons, or bosons depending on the particles involved in the interaction. Physicists study these interactions within quantum field theory via rudimentary models that are easier to understand, and are known as Feynman diagrams (Figure 2). 

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{figures/OIP.jpg}
    \caption{Feynman diagram showing the interaction of two charged electrons with the exchange (force carrier) being a photon in this case. Image from reference [2]}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

The repulsion can be observed via charged particles like electrons exchanging photons. The equations representing these physical processes can get very involved and hence Richard Feynman in 1949 developed these Feynman diagrams.

\subsection{History of QFT and Feynman Diagrams}
\begin{flushleft}
QFT or quantum field theory was first developed in the 1920s with the study of light and electrons. Normal quantum mechanics was unable to fully describe photons and relativistic particles nor particles within an electromagnetic framework. M. Born, W. Heisenberg, and P. Jordan (1926) in a joint paper sought out to extend the QM that the likes of Schrodinger, Heisenberg, Dirac, and Max Planck had developed in the 20th century into the area of electromagnetic fields. A year later, the birth of the first QFT, namely QED (quantum electrodynamics), was termed as such by Paul Dirac in his 1927 “The quantum theory of the emission and absorption of radiation” paper. In this paper, he explained how photons can appear within quantised states of a harmonic oscillator in electromagnetic fields of radiation. [3] 
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}


Richard Feynman introduced the Feynman diagrams in 1949 to compactly represent scattering processes and make it easier to calculate scattering amplitudes by outlining what is known as "Feynman rules" to these diagrams using field theory Lagrangian, with each line between the interacting particles representing an interaction term. This is relatively involved and not relevant to showcasing the modern methods of calculating scattering amplitudes, as such it will be left out.

\end{flushleft}

\section{Basic Kinematics}

The conservation of momentum and Lorentz invariance allows for constraints on the kinematics of scattering amplitudes and therefore will naturally deserve a brief review within this chapter. We will be first looking at the 4-momentum which is a relativistic treatment to momentum by extending it into 4D space-time. 

Traditionally the Newtonian momentum is 


\begin{center}
\begin{equation}
 p_i = (p_x,\text{ } p_y,\text{ } p_z)
 \end{equation}
\end{center}


where we have 3 spatial dimensions. 

The relativistic 4-vector is denoted with a greek letter and ranges from 0-3 with $p_0$ being the temporal component of momentum.
$$p_\mu = (p_0 , p_1, p_2, p_3) \text{ or }(p_0, p_i) $$



\subsection*{Mathematics}

\LaTeX{} is great at typesetting mathematics. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $\text{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\text{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 < \infty$, and let
$$S_n = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}
      = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X_i$$
denote their mean. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, the random variables $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \mu)$ converge in distribution to a normal $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.



\section*{Acknowledgments}

Additional information can be given in the template, such as to not include funder information in the acknowledgments section.

\bibliography{sample}
[1] AI generated image requested and described by [internet]. Accessed 27th July at <https://chatgpt.com/>

[2] Topquark (alias). Feynman Diagrams: An Introduction [Internet] Discover Hubpages. 2011 July 2 [cited 2024 July 27]. Available from <https://discover.hubpages.com/education/Feynman-Diagrams-An-Introduction>

[3] Kuhlmann, Meinard, "Quantum Field Theory", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Summer 2023 Edition), Edward N. Zalta and Uri Nodelman (eds.), [cited 2024 July 27] URL: <https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2023/entries/quantum-field-theory/>.
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

It is worth noting, I am new to Latex and only have about 2 days to submit my report so I am extremely pressed on time and I have searched on this forum and online about a solution so either I didn't find anything related or I missed a solution and copy-pasted things wrong. Maybe I have conflicting packages because asmath allegedly centres by default when you use \begin{equation} but I don't know!!

Welcome to TeX:SE!  Symbols $$ .... $$  are TeX command, not LaTeX. For LaTeX not numbered equation you should use \[ ...  \] or \begin{equation*} ... \end}equation}. For numbered just \begin{equation}....\end{{equation}.

fleqn usually left aligns equations. Remove that class option. What is oldplainarticle?

@Qrrbrbirlbel Hey I actually don't know what oldplainarticle is I was recommended to choose a template by my supervisor and the template I chose came with some of this code.

In the header of your document, you defined that the equations should be aligned to the left. Where it reads:
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{olplainarticle}

Remove the fleqn option, so that it reads:
\documentclass[10pt]{olplainarticle}

Compile again.

Omg THANK YOU SO MUCH. I can't believe the solution was that simple. Honestly you rock!

I don't know about olplainarticle, so I commented out the title parts.
The main issue is the fleqn option that's meant to place equation almost flush left.
However, there are several problems with your code. Please, take your time to read the following hints: your coding will be better and the output even more.

" should never be used in LaTeX; "exchange" should be
``exchange''


You should use symbolic references with the \label and \ref (or \eqref) method; the labels should not contain numbers, but remind something about the object.

$$ should never be used in a LaTeX document environment.

\text{Var} is wrong and should be \operatorname{Var}.

There's no reason for the flushleft environment.

Ties ~ should be used where shown in the code.

\text{ } is inappropriate where you used it.

A differential should be separated from the preceding symbols by \,.

For the “hand-made” bibliography, use the thebibliography environment.

A displayed equation should never be preceded by a blank line in the input code.


\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% Use option lineno for line numbers 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xurl}

% \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
% \setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip}

%\title{Modern Methods of Computing Scattering Amplitudes}
%\author[1]{}
%\affil[1]{Address of first author}

%\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}

%\begin{abstract}
%This report begins by introducing the concept of scattering 
%amplitudes and the motivation followed by review of spinor 
%helicity and the kinematics of special relativity, which will 
%be essential for our later discussion of discoveries for more 
%modern techniques to compute scattering amplitudes in a more 
%precise way than the traditional methods. We will then be fixing 
%three-point amplitudes using little group scaling followed by a 
%discussion of BCFW recursion relations with an overview of 
%residue theorem. Finally, we end the main discourse with the 
%derivation of Parke-Taylor formula for MHV amplitudes from BCFW 
%recursion relations. After this, we finalise the report with 
%closing remarks in a conclusion.
%\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Scattering Amplitudes}

What are scattering amplitudes and why study them? In QFT, 
or quantum field theory, scattering amplitudes are complex 
functions that measure the likelihood of particles scattering 
in a certain direction. The variation of the scattering angle 
is given by the differential cross-section given by the modulus 
of this probability amplitude (the complex function) squared as 
shown below in eq.~\eqref{eq:amplitude}.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:amplitude}
d\sigma=|f(\theta)|^2 \, d \Omega
\end{equation}

You can think of scattering processes as an ``exchange'' such as 
two people standing on a boat each and passing a ball to each 
other with the ball representing what is known as a ``force carrier'' 
in this analogy. Whenever a ball is thrown, the thrower will 
experience a reaction force and consequently his boat moves back. 
Likewise, when the other person catches the ball, he experiences a 
backwards force and is carried backwards from the momentum of the 
ball as illustrated rather questionably in figure~\ref{fig:boats}. 
It analogously demonstrates the phenomenon of repulsion.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
%\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{figures/97b445e5-5777-4f02-950f-c6d1e25d16a3.png}

\caption{Image portraying two ``boats'' and people throwing a yellow 
ball back and forth. Image generated by ChatGPT, reference~\cite{image}}
\label{fig:boats}

\end{figure}

This analogy simplifies particle interactions where this ``ball'', or 
force carrier, represents particles such as photons, gluons, or 
bosons depending on the particles involved in the interaction. 
Physicists study these interactions within quantum field theory 
via rudimentary models that are easier to understand, and are known 
as Feynman diagrams (Figure~\ref{fig:exchange}). 

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}
%\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{figures/OIP.jpg}

\caption{Feynman diagram showing the interaction of two charged 
electrons with the exchange (force carrier) being a photon in this 
case. Image from reference~\cite{topquark}}
\label{fig:exchange}

\end{figure}

The repulsion can be observed via charged particles like electrons 
exchanging photons. The equations representing these physical 
processes can get very involved and hence Richard Feynman in 1949 
developed these Feynman diagrams.

\subsection{History of QFT and Feynman Diagrams}

QFT or quantum field theory was first developed in the 1920s with 
the study of light and electrons. Normal quantum mechanics was unable 
to fully describe photons and relativistic particles nor particles 
within an electromagnetic framework. M.~Born, W.~Heisenberg, and 
P.~Jordan (1926) in a joint paper sought out to extend the QM that 
the likes of Schrodinger, Heisenberg, Dirac, and Max Planck had 
developed in the 20th century into the area of electromagnetic 
fields. A year later, the birth of the first QFT, namely QED 
(quantum electrodynamics), was termed as such by Paul Dirac in 
his 1927 ``The quantum theory of the emission and absorption of 
radiation'' paper. In this paper, he explained how photons can 
appear within quantised states of a harmonic oscillator in 
electromagnetic fields of radiation~\cite{kuhlmann}.

Richard Feynman introduced the Feynman diagrams in 1949 to 
compactly represent scattering processes and make it easier 
to calculate scattering amplitudes by outlining what is known 
as ``Feynman rules'' to these diagrams using field theory Lagrangian, 
with each line between the interacting particles representing an 
interaction term. This is relatively involved and not relevant to 
showcasing the modern methods of calculating scattering amplitudes, 
as such it will be left out.

\section{Basic Kinematics}

The conservation of momentum and Lorentz invariance allows for 
constraints on the kinematics of scattering amplitudes and therefore 
will naturally deserve a brief review within this chapter. We will 
be first looking at the 4-momentum which is a relativistic treatment 
to momentum by extending it into 4D space-time. 

Traditionally the Newtonian momentum is 
\begin{equation}
p_i = (p_x,p_y,p_z)
\end{equation}
where we have three spatial dimensions. 

The relativistic 4-vector is denoted with a greek letter and ranges 
from 0-3 with $p_0$ being the temporal component of momentum.
\[
p_\mu = (p_0 , p_1, p_2, p_3) \text{ or }(p_0, p_i)
\]

\section*{Acknowledgments}

Additional information can be given in the template, such as to 
not include funder information in the acknowledgments section.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{image} AI generated image requested and described by [internet]. 
Accessed 27th July at \url{https://chatgpt.com/}

\bibitem{topquark} Topquark (alias). Feynman Diagrams: An Introduction 
[Internet] Discover Hubpages. 2011 July 2 [cited 2024 July 27]. 
Available from \url{https://discover.hubpages.com/education/Feynman-Diagrams-An-Introduction}.

\bibitem{kuhlmann} Kuhlmann, Meinard, ``Quantum Field Theory'', The 
Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Summer 2023 Edition), 
Edward N. Zalta and Uri Nodelman (eds.), [cited 2024 July 27] 
URL: \url{https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/sum2023/entries/quantum-field-theory/}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}



Wow thanks for this. I will come back after my break and analyse it further. Wish I could upvote you guys but unfortunately the account is new
